# C++ check if string is beginning of an english word

Tags: c++, boggle

I've found a couple answers for how to check if a string is a full word, but nothing for how to check if a string is the first part of a word.

For example, I need a function that will return true for "c", "b", "cong" (congratulations, congruent, etc.), or "exa" (example, examine, etc.), but false for "congx", "qt", or other gibberish.

I'd imagine there are a number of ways to go about this. If you could provide a rough outline for a strategy, I would really appreciate it.
I'm trying to make a Boggle solver.
Thanks!

Comment: Regex with \b at the beginning but not at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Is `std::string part` *contained* in `std::string word`?

```
if(word.find(part) != std::string::npos)
{
    // part is in word somethere
}
```

Is `std::string part` at the *beginning* of `std::string word`?

```
if(word.find(part) == 0)
{
    // word starts with part
}
```

By way of explanation, [std::string::find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the *position* of what was found. So `0` means it was found at the beginning. The value [std::string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) is a special value that indicates nothing was found at all.

Comment: For _every_ word in a dictionary?

Comment: @Lol4t0 As far as I am aware these functions will work for *every* word in the dictionary but I must confess that I have not checked all of them.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I can get clever with this so that it doesn't take forever.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Ah well *now* I understand you. Maybe I misunderstood the question? I thought it was about comparing strings rather than strategies for searching a dictionary.

Comment: @ElliottShugerman Well for something like this I would turn to a dedicated dictionary library like [GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net/).

Comment: Well, my believe was that task is to check, if there is an _valid english word_, that starts with the given prefix.